# Can you look this sentence

Tags: grammaticality

> This might be taking several minutes.

Is this a correct sentence? It just doesn't sound correct.

Comment: Yes, they're slightly late. But they've just phoned to say there's a roadworks with a 4-way system of lights they need to get past. This might be taking several minutes.

Answer (score 2):

From a grammatical standpoint, the sentence is completely correct. But ( a very important **but**) language isn't just a set of words and tenses, phrases should dovetail into one another. In your case, It would be far better if you wrote **This might take several minutes**, expressing a bit of doubt about the possibility of taking several minutes. There is absolutely no need for the progressive aspect conveyed by **modal verb + be + -ing** , in your sentence -  **might be taking**.